# Express will Properly set CORS on localhost, but not on live server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I've tried a couple of things, and they both work on my localhost (headers are present and correct), but not on the live server , which is amazon hosted, built from a bitnami NodeJS image behind an apache reverse proxy.

Configurations I've tried:

1) Set response header manually for each route necessary (so this code was in a routing file):

```
router.options('/:var1/:var2', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Access-control-allow-origin", "*");
    var db = req.db;
    var data = db.get('data');
    actions.find({"criteria":req.params.var1}, function(err, docs)
    {
            res.send(docs);
    });
});
```

2) Use middleware from NPM (this code is in app.js):

```
//Includes/Requirements
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var cors = require('cors');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/app');

...

app.use(cors());
```

So using both of these techniques requests to localhost:3000 result in the expected headers (Access-allow-control-origin:*). However, when I push the code to my live server, those headers are not present in the responses.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your apache reverse proxy not forwarding all the headers from the upstream server, not a Node issue.

Comment: @furydevoid, thanks for the tip! I can't believe that didn't occur to me! I went to my server and specified the correct port to by-pass the reverse proxy and presto: the headers were there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it using cors module .

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors()); // add this line at appropriate place in your code
```

then add **app.options('*', cors());** before all the route is defined or included in server.js/app.js file